# Sub Domain handling in a Node js application

Tags: css, node.js, subdomain

I have a node.js application hosted on an AWS instance.

The directory structure is `user/app/public`. `index.js` lies within app and the public directory holds css, images, js & scripts as well as static HTML files.

Recently I moved from the existing `my_application.com/sites` to something like `sites.my_application.com`. Post performing the relevant changes the web pages worked fine except for one web page which for some reason is still hitting the old URL. Rest all work just fine. It is supposed to be a view web page based on Id. [image]

However the CSS and JavaScript and every request from here onwards keeps hitting the previous URL & hence instead of `site.my_application/view/id` I get `my_application/site/view/undefined`. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you'll want to focus your energy on your web server, are you using apache or nginx, errr?

Comment: Also, in the spirit of being helpful to new users, (per the blog post this past weekend), maybe we can better help this new user everyone ;) rather than just close it like jerks?

Comment: Could you share any relevant code which is making the request? Or your webserver config (nginx, apache) if used?

Comment: @JPSilvashy, previously we happened to be on nginx, now no longer

Comment: Also CORS is already taken care of. But I fail to understand the first url viewsoftware/171 hits the right url and then onwards the old url

Comment: Guys, thanks for your suggestions. The problem is solved. It was a very silly mistake on my part. On the AWS instance, I kept making changes to the files that were pulled from GitHub repository, the only catch was that they were present in a different User and were already a correct version of files. And the node js application was being run from a different user. So basically changes were being performed at a wrong place!